# Groovy : How to read xml tag names having full colon

Tags: groovy, xmldocument

I have an Xml tag   `<com:Id>33638</com:Id>` I want to read the value 33638 from the tag, I have parsed the `xml` string and stored to another string variable but cant read the value using

```
String id  = 'com:Id'.text();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine:

```
def t = "<com:Id>33638</com:Id>"
def xml = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(t)
println xml.text()
```

Comment: Thank you.. it works...  if I'm using XmlSlurper is it possible to do so..??

Comment: Sure. Just change the class.

Comment: def t = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText( t ) not reading <com:id> text ??

Comment: Replace `xml` variable declaration with: `def xml = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(t)` and it works fine.

Comment: def xml = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(t) while using xmlslurper getting value as ""

Comment: No idea what's wrong :( Maybe it's version problem? I've `2.2.1`